# Entity Framework and string as NCLOB on oracle Db

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, code-first, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have this model:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set: }
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
}
```

and when Model First run, it creates my Teachers table and DbSet, but for Name and Surname (which are string) it assigns NCLOB type to the column. 
Now, with NCLOB type I cannot do some operations like equals or distincts on my table....

How can I force MF to set columntype to varchar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue setting the maximum string lenght into the model

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "My Error Message")]
    public string Name { get; set: }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "My Error Message")]
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
}
```

Without the StringLength Orcale creates a NCLOB field that can contain up to 4Gb of data.

Note: Maximum lenght for varchar is 4000 bytes, so we cannot set more than 2000 as MaximumLenght (2 byte per character with Unicode)

Comment: I have an int with a .ToString() in a LINQ query and it is using TO_NCLOB in the query that is created. Is there there any way of preventing that?

Comment: @JonathanPeel If the int is available outside of the LINQ query, you could convert the int to a local string variable outside of LINQ, and use the string in the LINQ query.

Comment: I found a way to map extentions methods to Oracle functions, using `[Function(FunctionType.BuiltInFunction, "TO_CHAR")]`. I then created an `int.ToChar()`, and it works wonderfully.

Comment: @JonathanPeel  How did you get this work? I can't seem to. I am using database first and have a generated edmx file. This is the error: "The specified method 'System.String ToChar(Int64)' on the type 'Acorn.Data.OracleFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.""

Comment: I am using code first, on an existing DB. `OracleFunctions` is a static class, with members like `[Function(FunctionType.BuiltInFunction, "TO_CHAR")]
        public static string ToChar(this int value) => Function.CallNotSupported<string>();`  In the DbContext class There is a method called `OnModelCreating`. There is a line of code in there: `modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention(typeof(OracleFunctions)));`

Comment: With DB first, the code files are _generated by a tool_, so it is not a good idea to change them. The DbContext class might be `partial`. If it is, you can create another `partial class` with the same name in a different file. This then won't be overridden if you update the edmx.

Comment: If you don't come right, let me know, and I will send you a sample. It is difficult explaining in comments.

Comment: @JonathanPeel  I didn't realize that library only worked with Code First. Converted to Code First and added the FunctionConvention in OnModelCreating and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try to configure it explicitly:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnType("varchar");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Property(x => x.Surname).HasColumnType("varchar");
}
```

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: I've managed to solve it the 'right way'. I'll post the answer but thank anyway for the effort!

Comment: only should be `varchar2`?