# Forcing Entity Framework to not generate NCLOB's when building Linq-to-Sql Code (Model First)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a class with a nullable int property that that for filtering reasons, I need to convert to a string to do some comparisons. I have EF 6.1.2 installed, so using a .ToString() will work for that.

```
queryableData = queryableData.Where(a => 
    a.PropName.HasValue && a.PropName.Value.ToString().Contains("8675309"));
```

When examining the actual SQL being executed, the number is being CAST into an NCLOB type, which is resulting in the following error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR - got NCLOB

From what I've read, this is because Entity is unaware of the potential max size in this case, so it defaults to the largest option. I know with a string property that I would be able to denote a max size to help. Is there anything that I can do while keeping the property as an int to prevent the NCLOB's from being used? Or a way to use them while preventing this exception?

Some other notes:

- I'm on an Oracle System, so SqlFunctions.StringConvert is out.
- I'm on Odp.net version 12.x (related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607790/getting-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-got-clob-with-database-fir)).
- The EF is a Model-First approach.
- The .Where() clause is being added to an AsQueryable(), so I can't do anything in memory.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with Oracle (*Oracle 11.2.02 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.2.1100*) and Entity Framework (*EntityFramework.6.1.3*).

This inside Linq code (the property "Id" is integer):

`Material.Id.ToString()`

Generates this SQL:

`(CASE WHEN ("Extent3"."Material_Id" IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE TO_NCLOB("Extent3"."Material_Id") END)`

And the problem is **TO_NCLOB**, it should be **TO_NCHAR**

**Solution**
[JonathanPeel comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525078/entity-framework-and-string-as-nclob-on-oracle-db)
[Install-Package EntityFramework.Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271718/oracle-entity-framework-call-custom-function-edit-distance)