# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got NCLOB

Tags: oracle, asp.net-web-api

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6 library is used to access to an Oracle Database from WebApi MVC ASP.Net application. It is the latest library version from the NuGet as of November, 14th 2017

```
    public IEnumerable<Milad.Models.DomainModels.A_LASTNOBAT> GetGis(string id)
{

var model3 = blnobat.Select().OrderBy(p => p.A_NOBAT).Where(p => p.A_COUNTERNO.Value.ToString().Contains(id));
return (model3).Tostring();
}
```

type of A_COUNTERNO in database is number.when i run program ,visual studio show this error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got NCLOB
thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing Entity Framework to not generate NCLOB's when building Linq-to-Sql Code (Model First)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179112/forcing-entity-framework-to-not-generate-nclobs-when-building-linq-to-sql-code)